# How to delete all companies or contacts?

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm

I'm using the free HubSpot CRM for now.  I wrote some scraping code and through the API added over 17k companies and 4k contacts.

There were some errors due to an incomplete understanding of some of the API calls and now I'd like to wipe everything out and start over.

I realize I could run the "Get Recently Created Companies" and for each of the 20 it returns run the delete company API call, then loop it until no companies exist, however this seems like something I shouldn't have to write code to accomplish.

I checked the Academy but the examples showed an interface that didn't match what I see, so it's either outdated or meant for a different version of HubSpot than I have.  Didn't find much on Google either.

Anyone else know of an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HubSpot developer here. I just checked with the folks who run the Contacts and Companies APIs – the best option you have right now is to [contact support](http://help.hubspot.com/support).

I know that's not the answer you're looking for. We're working on improving things, but it's not there yet.

Comment: Thank you.  It helps to know that there wasn't another solution out there.  In this case it turns out I needed to create a new account anyway.  I'll keep on the lookout for solutions to this in the future if the need arises again.  I know those guys are also working to improve the Company API methods as well.  Keep up the good work, been using HubSpot for years and it's a great product.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this issue myself, needing to delete 8k test the marketing team had generated when we were still playing around with features. Had to reach out to customer support a few times to get the answer as it's not at all intuitive.

On [this help page](http://knowledge.hubspot.com/lists-user-guide/how-to-delete-a-list-of-contacts) they say that you can mass delete contacts by adding them to a list, using `Select All`, and then `Delete`. This doesn't work in cases such as mine though as the pagination only allows you to see up to 100 contacts at a time.

The secret step for now is that you have to go down to the bottom right corner and click on "View the old list manager" (black square button with two arrows that's just to the side of the Help button). In this view `Select All` really does select every contact in the list so that you can perform a batch delete (or other action) on them all at once.

#### Summary

1. Create new list with rules to add the Contacts you want to delete
2. Switch to the old list manager view (button on bottom right)
3. Select All
4. Delete
5. Tell the confirmation box that yes, you really know what you're doing

Hopefully HubSpot will update their help docs soon and re-add the ability to really select all list items in the new view before they completely remove the option to switch back the old view.